# IRremote Library causes SD Card to stop… Why?

Tags: arduino, sd-card, infrared

I'm tring to use IRremote Library with the SD card library but it doesn't work, even if I just import the IRremote library, the SD card stops to work immediately anyone knows why?

Here's some code which i'm working with.

http://pastebin.com/Fth9Lftb

NOTE: IF I COMMENT THE LINE "#include " it works, can ANYONE help me pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

You ask why?
The IRremote library messes with the Arduino timers.

It's possible to change the timer it uses.

In `IRremoteInt.h` it says:

> // Uncomment the timer you wish to use on your board.  If you
>   // are using another library which uses timer2, you have options
>   // to switch IRremote to use a different timer.

That's worth a try!